# Duplicate/Aliased MVC routing

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have an MVC 5 application, for which I have just completed a booking process. The process uses a BookingController using the standard default route:

> "{controller}/{action}/{aId}"

However I now have a request to provide the ability to do a quote process. The quote process is **IDENTICAL** to the booking process except that certain page headings will change. The other requirement being that instead of a url in the form:

> /booking/process

the url has to be:

> /quote/process

Now while I certainly could add the following route config:

```
aRoutes.MapRoute("QuoteSameAsBookingWhichUsesDefault", "quote/process", new
     {
         controller = MVC.Booking.Name,
         area = "" //Work around bug in T4MVC 
     });
}
```

this is not going to help me as within the BookingController I naturally do things like:

```
return RedirectToAction(MVC.Booking.ActionNames.BookingAlreadyProcessed);
```

and of course the routing will now get confused because assuming I put the above route configuration about the default route my booking url will now also be:

**/quote/process** instead of **/booking/process**

I don't want to copy code sideways to achieve this, but just how do I do this? That is - Identical behaviour with just the url changed.

Comment: Rename the controller? Or seriously, attribute routing?

Comment: How can I use attribute routing?

Answer (score 0):

Even though you can write a route definition to use same action method for both the pages, That can get dirty real quick. Why not have a BookingController and a QuoteController and have the Process action method in both ? If you want to use the same markup, you can create partial view(s) and use those in the Process views.

```
public class BookingController : Controller
{
   public ActionResult Process()
   {
       var vm = new ProcessViewModel();
       //set some properties on vm as needed
       return View(vm);
   }
   [HttpPost]
   public ActionResult Process(ProcessViewModel model)
   {
      // to do : Save and redirect        
   }
}
public class QuoteController : Controller
{
   public ActionResult Process()
   {
      var vm = new ProcessViewModel();
       //set some properties on vm as needed
      return View(vm);
   }
   [HttpPost]
   public ActionResult Process(ProcessViewModel model)
   {
      // to do : Save and redirect
   }
}
```

You do not need any specific-custom route definition for this approach. The default route definition is enough.

You can use the common view model for both the views. Adjust the property values as needed.

```
public class ProcessViewModel
{
  public int NumberOfDays {set;get;}
  //Add any other properties for your view as needed
}
```

Comment: Issue becomes the code duplication in Process(ProcessViewModel model).

Comment: @TheEdge If you want, You can post to the same HttpPost action method by specifying the target form in your `Html.Beginform` helper method in the razor views.

Answer (score 0):

If the quote process and booking process are identical, you should create a service to do the processing and inject the service into both controllers.

```
public interface IBookingProcessor
{
    ProcessViewModel Process(ProcessViewModel model);
}

public class BookingProcessor : IBookingProcessor
{
    public ProcessViewModel Process(ProcessViewModel model)
    {
        // Add the common logic here
    }
}

public class BookingController : Controller
{
    private readonly IBookingProcessor bookingProcessor;

    public BookingController(IBookingProcessor bookingProcessor)
    {
        if (bookingProcessor == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("bookingProcessor");
        this.bookingProcessor = bookingProcessor;
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Process(ProcessViewModel model)
    {
        var vm = this.bookingProcessor.Process(model);

        //set some properties on vm as needed

        //Return the result
        return View(vm);
    }
}
public class QuoteController : Controller
{
    private readonly IBookingProcessor bookingProcessor;

    public BookingController(IBookingProcessor bookingProcessor)
    {
        if (bookingProcessor == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("bookingProcessor");
        this.bookingProcessor = bookingProcessor;
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Process(ProcessViewModel model)
    {
        var vm = this.bookingProcessor.Process(model);

        //set some properties on vm as needed

        //Return the result
        return View(vm);
    }
}
```

If you decouple your business logic from your controllers it will be much easier to reuse the business logic in other controllers without copying a lot of code. I don't really see the point of making a separate route in this case, the default route will serve your need.

Then all you need is an IoC container such as [Autofac](http://autofac.org/) or [StructureMap](http://structuremap.github.io/) wired into a custom IControllerFactory to provide instances of services to your controllers (and other services) as needed.

Technically, your service shouldn't depend directly on the ProcessViewModel, but an interface that it implements or simply by passing properties into the service, but this example provides a starting point.